# JavaScript comparison issues

Tags: javascript, comparison

I need this comparison in my javascript to work.

```
if ((q2 != '' && correct2 != 'True') || (q2 != '' && correct2 != 'true') || (q2 != '' && correct2 != 'false') || (q2 != '' && correct2 != 'False'))
{
    alert("You must enter true or false.");
}
```

q2 and correct2 are textboxes and if q2 has something in it and correct2 doesn't equal true, True, false, or False then I want the message box pops up. My code is not working. If I put true or false in the blank the error message still shows up.

EDIT

I have found how to make it work. Instead of putting || between the comparisons I put && and it works perfectly.

Comment: Now that you've fixed the syntax error, fix the question. Create a *minimal* test-case - this should include values for which the expression works and for which it doesn't work as well - that shows what "doesn't work" and *explain why* it "doesn't work" and what is expected. Then, I'll go find you a duplicate. Hints: `q || 'True'` is *always* a true expression and `x || y || z` is the same as `(x || y) || z`.

Comment: Okay, please stop randomly changing your code .. especially without acknowledgement to what it was before.

Comment: Ok I knew that you could not have or I was just simplifying. The code above is exactly what I want to happen but it doesnt. When I do enter true or false in the blank it still shows the alert box.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of a text input, do  something like

`var q2Value = q2.value;`

For the conditionals, `||` is or, not `or`, and everytime you do a comparison you need 2 values/variables

`(correct2 !== 'True ) || (correct2 !== 'true')...`

You can see I wrapped the comparisons in parenthesis so its perfectly clear what should be compared to what, even if it isn't strictly necessary.

Since you need q2 to be correct before comparing the other condition, you can use a nifty feature called short-circuiting.  Basically, `&&` only proceeds if the first comparison is truthy, so you would do

`(qa2 !== '') && (the rest)`

Note that if a user doesn't enter the value at all, when you get the value of the text field it will be `undefined` (I think), not `''`'. So you should really just do

`qa2 && (...)`

Basically `null`, `undefined`, and `''` are all falsy in javascript, so if qa2 is any of those values, the second part of the and won't be processed.

Comment: I am making a printable quiz/test generator. This is not for any class. I dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: I need it to have q2 != '' first. If nothing is entered into q2 then this comparison doesnt apply.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
if ((q2 != '' && correct2 != 'True') || (q2 != '' && correct2 != 'true') || (q2 != '' && correct2 != 'false') || (q2 != '' && correct2 != 'False'))
{
    alert("You must enter true or false.");
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question q2 and correct2 are **textboxes**. The OP needs to know how to get those values into the js.

Comment: I don't think his problem is related to how to read the values from html into JS.  I think he is having a syntax issue. 

If he needs help loading the values of the html elements into JS he could add these lines right before what I posted above.

var q2 = document.getElementById("idOfQ2TextBox");
var correct2 = document.getElementById("idOfCorrect2TextBox");

Comment: @njtman No I am able to read the values because if I just put in if(q2 != '' && correct2 != 'true then I type true in the box it works.

Comment: @Dustin H, Thats what I figured, but for some reason Lee Taylor thinks he knows better than you what you are asking 0_o.  Try the code I posted in the answer and see if it works.

Comment: @Dustin H, it is very possible to do what you want to do.  You may need to include more code in your OP so we can better understand the issue you are having.  The syntax of your OP is not correct.  The correct syntax is posted in my answer.  If it still doesn't work, something else is causing the issue.  Try to use the Chrome debugger to help you find out what the issue is.

Comment: @njtman nothing comes up in the debugger. There are no errors it just doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if(q2 !== '' && !(correct2 == 'true') && !(correct2 == 'True') && !(correct2 == 'False') && !(correct2 == 'false'))
{
    alert("You must enter true or false.")
};
```

Comment: As stated in the question q2 and correct2 are **textboxes**. The OP needs to know how to get those values into the js.